# Rails: send email in different languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my app I need to send emails in different languages. How it would be done correctly - make different email templates `invite.en.text.erb` and `invite.de.text.erb` for example (not sure that will work), keep email messages in I18n localizations or other solutions maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use localized views (link to Rails Guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#localized-views)), which do exactly as you suggest. Simply rename the view files as shown, and they will automatically interact with your Rails localization settings.

To send mails in a given locale depending on the User's locale, email address, or some other logic, you can use the I18n.with_locale(locale) method. An example of a Mailer using a similar method is shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11248315/660936) SO answer.

I would not suggest doing what HendrikPetertje is suggesting. It clutters your locale file with localization strings that are only used for single views.

Answer (score 1):

create the default email files (like the one you would use normaly) and try the instructions below:

In your email file:

```
<p><%= t('email_line_description_here')%></p>
<p><%= t('email_line2_description_here') %></p>
(etc)
```

In your config/locales/en.yml (the right indentation is important here)

```
en:
  # email stuff
  email_line_description_here: "Your email's first line content in English here"
  email_line2_description_here: "Your email's second line content in English here"
```

In your config/locales/de.yml (the right indentation is important here as well)

```
de:
  # email stuff
  email_line_description_here: "Your email's first line content in German here"
  email_line2_description_here: "Your email's second line content in German here"
```

Now when the environment is set to English lines will be translated according to the en.yml if German translation will be done acording to de.yml.

Comment: More info on internationalisation and translation stuff here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html